# Popup Window is opening properly but changing main window URL

Tags: javascript, html

This is the code I'm using :

```
<a href="javascript:window.open(' http://eepurl.com/bQhLz1', 
   'Health Challenge: Week One', 'width=600,height=550 ');" ></a>
```

Not sure why my main page URL is redirecting once the popup opens. What can I do to fix this?

Demo: http://www.kaytivstheworld.com/2016/01/health-challenge-week-one.html

Comment: Works as it should for me? In chrome - which browser are you using?

Comment: [Don't use `href="javascript:"` or `onclick=""`.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35093997/3853934)

Comment: Alternate duplicate targets: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622100/how-can-i-disable-href-if-onclick-is-executed or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607865/is-it-possible-to-stop-the-browser-from-following-the-link-when-the-onclick-of-t

Answer (score 0):

You should open window through `onclick` event and also `return false` to prevent default action

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://eepurl.com/bQhLz1',
'Health Challenge: Week One', 'width=600,height=550'); return false;"></a>
```

Comment: its an easy solution then why down vote.