# Popup window opens but does not close automatically

Tags: javascript

I need to automatically close the window that I've opened with the javascript below. The popup window is opening correctly, but it does not close automatically in 1 second.

```js
<script>
function myFunction() {
  window.open("http://google.com", "_blank", "toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,top=50,left=250,width=300,height=150"); setTimeout("window.close();", 1000)
}
</script>
```

Can someone please help fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your `settimeout` is just calling a string, which is not a function.

You also need to get a reference to the pop-up then call the close on the reference:

```
<script>
function myFunction(e, anchor) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent navigation to page
    var popup = window.open("http://google.com", "_blank", "toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,top=50,left=250,width=300,height=150");
    setTimeout(function(){
        popup.close();
        // Continue navigating to link
        window.location.href = anchor.getAttribute("href");
    }, 1000);
}
</script>


<a href="https://yahoo.com" onclick="myFunction(event, this)"> <span class="tcb-button-texts">TRY IT NOW</span> </a>
```

Comment: So the popup opening and closing now works. 

Here is my use case:
1) On click of a button (I'm using a href) a new page is supposed to load.
2) The popup is supposed to open and close automatically.

Part (2) is working well, by itself. But if I combine it with part (1) it does not work. Meaning, the desired page opens and the pop opens on top of it; but the popup does not close automatically.

Comment: If it is an anchor link that causes the browser to navigate to a different link the browser is unloading which means further scripts will not run (including your pop-up script). You need to remove the link or interrupt it ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607865/is-it-possible-to-stop-the-browser-from-following-the-link-when-the-onclick-of-t ) until your pop-up script runs.

Comment: This is how I'm trying to initiate two things on the click of a button.
1) Open a specific page (i've used yahoo.com as an example)
2) Open a 'Thank You' page in a popup window and close it in 3 seconds.

This is the html code:
<a href="http://yahoo.com" onclick="myFunction()">
 <span class="tcb-button-texts">TRY IT NOW</span>
</a>

Comment: As stated, the pop-up needs to run first. You need to prevent the navigation from occurring (see the `click` event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click ) until the pop-up has closed or the actions will not complete as intended.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I get the theory and logic. I'm struggling with how to implement it via the right code.

Comment: Hi Jim. While the popup opens and auto closes... yahoo.com does not load.

Comment: Drat, I thought you would figure this one out. It is now 99% there. The rest is up to you. Your hint is to try the link without the function... where does it go?

Comment: In another instance of the above use case, I'm using a 'button' for the click where type="submit" is there instead of href="something.html"

I'm assuming I need to change this line of code:
window.location.href = anchor.getAttribute("href");

Please advice whet I should replace it with? And if there is anything else that I may need to edit?